# Express returns servers' automatic HTML error page, instead of my res.json error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, plesk

I have a REST api on the express server and React app for front-end. I have designed it to send JSON to front-end when faces an error, it sends it and I can use it to print errors on the client side as a modal etc. this is my route file for user/login(I also use JWT and bcrypt for password issues):

```
router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  //simple validation
  if (!email || !password) {
    return res.status(400).json({ general: "Email and Password can not be empty" });
  }

  //check for existing user
  User.findOne({ email }).then((err, user) => {
    if (!user)
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "This user doesn't exist"});
    if (err) console.log(err);
    //Validate password
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(isMatch => {
      if (!isMatch)
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ password: "Password and User name are not match!" });

      jwt.sign(
        { id: user.id },
        config.get("jwtSecret"),
        { expiresIn: 3600 },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json({
            token,
            user: {
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              email: user.email,
              sort: user.sort
            }
          });
        }
      );
    });
  });
});
```

and my app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const config = require("config");

const app = express();

//Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB config

const db = config.get("mongoURI");

//connect to Mongo
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected..."))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

//Use routes
app.use("/api/test", require("./routes/api/test"));
app.use("/api/users", require("./routes/api/users"));
app.use("/api/tickets", require("./routes/api/tickets"));


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

On Localhost there is no problem. But after uploading to the server, when I left empty spaces or submit false password etc, it never sends my JSON responses, instead, it returns servers Html Page. I console.logged returning error response and it is something like this:

[image]

How can I replace the Html response with my own JSON error message?

Comment: are you using any global error handler for express?

Comment: hmm I think no. I mean I put these responses in routes, there is no additional error middleware or something

Comment: Try using catch with err. If you have any error in the code then it will be thrown there. By that way you can debug your database errors which is not visible by seeing code only. 

User.findOne().then().catch(err => { console.log(err); return res.status(500).json(err)  })

Comment: It seems In my local backend, it returns data object with my string in it(the one I send with res.json). But on the server, it overwrites my string with automated "Bad request" string in data object. My goal is disable this overwriting

Comment: what happens when you try without json? like `res.status(400).send("This user doesn't exist");`

Comment: Nothing changes. Just with blank credentials, it gives 404 error with data, an HTML page. if I submit wrong -mail and password then it gives 400 error with data "Bad request"

Comment: I really didnt understand the logic. Where are the settings to disable this error responses ?, because in my localhost, my json responses works well

Comment: You're saying that it works as expected on your local machine. Is it possible that the remote server has some kind of a proxy in front of your app, like nginx? It is not unusual to have a reverse proxy configured to serve a static error html page when an upstream responds with an error code.

Comment: @shkaper it is probably something like that. But how can I detect it ? It is Plesk Obsidian, the configuration, and the other stuff, I look at all options but couldn't find anything useful

Comment: I resolved the problem. Check my answer

Comment: You are not defining a `catch` to handle the thrown error. If an error is thrown and you don't catch it and then explicitly return json, it won't send back json.  You need to re-evaluate your answer. There is no need to go into the web config file

Comment: @skellertor You say if I send error like `function(err, req, res)`, instead of returning res.json, it will not be prevented by the server, The issue is my style of handling errors? I will gonna try that, it sounds logical

Comment: You just need to define a `.catch` as @SamarthSaxena shows in his comment.  The problem is the `if (err) throw err`. When you throw that error that is nothing to handle it. The `.catch` will "catch" it then you can explicitly return json

Answer (score 3):

The default error handler shows the error as an HTML page.

See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

You can override the default error handler. Try adding this to the end of your app.js.

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next) {
    next({ status: 404 });
});

app.use(function (err: any, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(err.status || 500).json();
});
```

Comment: The part about putting it at "the end of your app.js" file saved my bacon. It wasn't working for me until I put it as the last middleware.

Answer (score -1):

i guess you are using axios?

did you try it with:

```
.then(err => {
   err.response.data
})
```

Your response is actually in `err.response`